# Setting Android Key Board Type

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-keypad

I'm new to Android development. For that reason, I apologize if this is a dumb question. I have honestly tried to figure this out and read a number of related questions without any success.

I have a basic app running in [image: the android 3.1 emulator]. From the screenshot, you can see how the keyboard focused on numbers displays. I just want to show the basic qwerty-esque keyboard. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it. Currently, I've set the imeOption to normal thinking that would do it. I also tried setting the inputType to 'normal' without any luck. Here's the relevant pieces of my Android Layout file.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:imeOptions="normal"
  android:inputType="text"
  ...
/>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I show the basic qwerty-style keyboard in Android? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the actual layout, not just some arbitrary subset.

Comment: YOur problem might be related to the device type selected by your AVD manager. Try starting a different device image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TanjaV said, this keyboard is for devices with a physical keyboard where the avd will not change it regardless of your input type.

Change your AVD devices to something such as Nexus4, or Nexus One (if you want older model), then you should see the keyboard changing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights. That was the problem.